# Who Edited my Comment, & How?

Tags: discussion

Before lunch, I lazily (with as much effort as the asker) posted a link to the String class's documentation.

When I came back from lunch, my comment had been edited with code formatting & a proper link.

I'm not debating the quality of the edit, but I've never seen a comment edited by someone else before. Was this an automated edit, or did someone come along and use privileges I'm not familiar with?

[How to Concatenate, Left and Len in Salesforce Trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206360/how-to-concatenate-left-and-len-in-salesforce-trigger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was me. Mods can do that.

I did so because I was reading the link url and saw something like:

```
developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us...
```

Which tells me nothing about the link content. So I made it a little more clear where the link is pointing.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the site! I figured it was a mod only thing, but I've never seen or heard of comment editing until now.

Comment: It's pretty rare. I avoid it unless I think  there's a clear benefit.